# TableDnD is not working with span in td jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, drag-and-drop

I am creating a table in which I have draggable tr, I used [TableDnD](https://rawgit.com/isocra/TableDnD/master/js/jquery.tablednd.js) for draggable component.

The code look like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var iCnt = 1;
    $("#tblQuestionAns tr").each(function () {
        var id = "tr" + parseInt(iCnt);
        $(this).attr("id", id);
        iCnt++;
    });
    $("#tblQuestionAns").find("tr :even").addClass("even");
    $("#tblQuestionAns").find("tr :odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#tblQuestionAns").tableDnD({
        onDragClass: "myDragClass",
        onDrop: function (table, row) {
            $("#tblQuestionAns").find("tr").removeClass("even odd");
            $("#tblQuestionAns").find("tr :even").addClass("even");
            $("#tblQuestionAns").find("tr :odd").addClass("odd");
        }
    });
});
```

This is working when I create a table like the following:

```
<table id="tblQuestionAns">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Test1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Test2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but when I add span in td, it will not work, here is an example:

```
<table id="tblQuestionAns">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Test1</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Test2</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is [JSFiddle for your reference](https://jsfiddle.net/dvzhfqmc/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to disable pointer events on span?
It's working fine for me. Not sure if this is what you're trying to accomplish.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var iCnt = 1;
  $(".tblQuestionAns tr").each(function() {
    var id = "tr" + parseInt(iCnt);
    $(this).attr("id", id);
    iCnt++;
  });
  $(".tblQuestionAns").find("tr :even").addClass("even");
  $(".tblQuestionAns").find("tr :odd").addClass("odd");
  $(".tblQuestionAns").tableDnD({
    onDragClass: "myDragClass",
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
      $(".tblQuestionAns").find("tr").removeClass("even odd");
      $(".tblQuestionAns").find("tr :even").addClass("even");
      $(".tblQuestionAns").find("tr :odd").addClass("odd");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/isocra/TableDnD/master/js/jquery.tablednd.js"></script>
<div>
  without span
</div>
<table class="tblQuestionAns">
  <tr>
    <td>
      test1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      test2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
  with span
</div>
<table class="tblQuestionAns">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>test1</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>test2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```